# Is it safe to ask the user for their API credentials to fetch information?

Tags: paypal

I am building an analytics web application for PayPal. Currently, when the user signs up on my app, I ask them to enter their API Key, Password and Secret. Then I use PayPal's Classic API to retrieve transaction history. Although I only use the API credentials to retrieve the info and don't actually store it in my database (only store transaction history information), I'm not sure if this is the best or safest method.

I didn't find any "Connect to PayPal" type mechanism that other services (like Stripe) offer. So is the way I am doing it the only good way?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how your application works.  If the user is going to download the application to their computer and run it directly from their computer (or install it on their own web servers and run it from there), then yes — asking them for their API credentials is the right way to go.

If the user is going to run the application from your own servers, then it's generally better to ask them for permissions using something like the [Permissions Service](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/gs_PermissionsService/) instead.

Comment: I am actually building a prototype. Getting Permissions service to work requires me to create an app, where I have to enter all sort of official information (which has not been finalized yet). As a result, I have no choice but to ask directly for API credentials, it seems.

Comment: You can integrate in the Sandbox without having to create an app.  Use app ID `APP-80W284485P519543T` and the credentials that you got from your Sandbox account.